# Why I can't compare dates?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have this simple query:

```
select sm.id, h.time
from main_data sm

INNER JOIN TA t on t.id = sm.id AND t.first=1
LEFT OUTER JOIN History h on h.id= sm.id

WHERE trunc(TO_DATE(h.time, 'DD-MM-YYYY')) BETWEEN trunc(TO_DATE('07.05.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY')) AND trunc(TO_DATE('07.06.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY'));
```

`h.time` looks like `07-MAY-15`

The above query returns no results, even if there are dates between the specified parameters. **BUT** if I change the where clause to

`WHERE trunc(TO_DATE(h.time, 'DD-MM-YYYY')) BETWEEN trunc(TO_DATE('07.05.15', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) AND trunc(TO_DATE('07.06.15', 'DD-MM-YYYY'))` 
- the same dates but instead of `2015` there is just `15` I can see the results of the query.

The problem is that I'm expecting the user to enter a full year - not just `15`. How can I avoid this mismatch?

Comment: Your parameter and your format mask don't match in the `to_date()` call. `'07.06.15'` using `.` as the separator vs. `'DD-MM-YYYY'` using a `-` as the separator. You also told Oracle that your year is supplied with four digits, but your value only contains two.

Comment: Additionally: which data type is `h.time`? If that already _is_ a date converting the `date` to a `date` using `to_date()` makes no sense whatsoever - what's worse: it will result in a wrong date value because `to_date()` expects a varchar so your perfectly find `date` is converted to a varchar (based on implicit rules) and then converted back to a date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your date comparison is too complicated.  If `h.time` is an internal date format (which it should be), then just do:

```
WHERE h.time BETWEEN DATE '2015-05-07' AND DATE '2015-06-07'
```

Another very important issue with your query is that the `WHERE` clause is turning the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.  Either change the join type to be consistent with the logic or move the `WHERE` to the `ON` clause (you will then get results even when there are no matching dates.